# Invalid link forces Internet Explorer to close

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a web page with some javascript like this:

```
location = '../AnotherPage.html';
```

If AnotherPage.html exists, all is well.  If it doesn't, then I get two behaviours.  If this is all running on my local machine, I get an "Access is denied" error.  But if the pages are on another machine and I'm accessing it via a share, Internet Explorer just silently closes.

As far as I can tell, no error is generated, and I have a try-catch block around the line that isn't tripped. All I want to do is prevent IE from closing.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like IE is simply crashing, which means you've got an installation problem rather than a programming one. Does it happen on any other machine? What do you have installed? Multiple IEs, dodgy plugins, BHOs, unstable AV software?

Comment: Not much luck there sorry.  It happens on more than one machine, and there isn't anything unusual installed that I know of.

I agree that it is probably a crash, although it seems odd that it fails so quietly.  There is no error dialog or anything